# Initialize variable inside method

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I initialize a variable like this:

Suppose that we have:

```
T obj = GetT();
```

in aspx page. (`GetT()` can return null value).
And I want to handle this obj inside a function

```
public void HandlingT(T obj){
    if(condition && obj == null){
        obj = new T();
    }
    //...handling object T
}
```

So we get:

```
T obj = GetT();
HandlingT(obj);
```

The problem is, when I call the function `HandlingT()` in aspx page, `obj` is still null even if the `condition` is true

Comment: Or should I put the address of T in the handlingT() method instead?

Comment: Can you include the ASPX side of the code?

Comment: Try  `HandlingT(out T obj)`

Comment: You aren't initializing the variable. You are *changing* the object that the *property* obj points to. *Not* the variable.

Comment: or `ref`. Why does `GetT` return `null`?

Comment: If you're trying to use the original `obj` after calling `HandingT(obj)` you should use `HandlingT(ref T obj)` as the function prototype.  Do not use `out` because `out` requires you to set a new value for `obj`.

Comment: Instead of changing the *property* to `out` or `ref`, modify the functin to actually return the modified object.

Comment: @combatc2 the aspx page is not like this, I turned it to be easier to read

Comment: thanks guys, it worked

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `obj` *is* a variable.  It's *not* a property.  The OP's code *is* changing the variable.  You have your terminology completely reversed.  Additionally, the OP uses the term "initializing" correctly; they *are* initializing a variable at that point.

Comment: @Servy oops, I thought I typed `parameter`. As it is, the code *inside* the method is modifying the parameter, not the variable. There are two different things that just happen to have the same name but different scopes. A parameter named `obj` in a method, and a variable named `obj` outside that method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A parameter is a type of variable, so yes it *is* a variable.  It's *also* a parameter.  It's not the *same* variable as the one provided as an argument; it's a *different* variable, but it *is* still a variable.

Comment: @Servy whatever. Nice that we agree. I have another question about dataflows on the stove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing references with values.  When you do this:

```
T obj = GetT();
HandlingT(obj);
```

And then inside of the `HandlingT` method do this:

```
obj = new T();
```

That does *nothing* to the `obj` variable created *outside* of that method.  The variables coincidentally have the same name, but they are not the same variable.  What you're doing is creating an instance of `T` and assigning it to the *local* variable in the method.  If you want to assign that reference to the variable outside of the method, that assignment has to be performed on *that* variable.

So for example you could *return* the instance from the method:

```
public T HandlingT(T obj){
    if(condition && obj == null){
        obj = new T();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And use that returned value outside of the method:

```
T obj = GetT();
obj = HandlingT(obj);
```

Basically, an *assignment* happens to a variable, not to an in-memory object.  If you reference the object with the variable, you can change that in-memory object.  But if you assign the variable to a new object, you're not changing what the variable originally pointed to, you're just pointing it to something else.

Consider this:

```
void DoSomething(MyObj obj)
{
    obj = new MyObj();
    obj.Something = "foo";
}
```

That example does nothing to the instance which was originally passed to the method.  A new instance is created and is only referenced within the method.  Once the method exits, that instance is garbage-collected and the original instance which was passed to the method is unmodified.

Contrast to this:

```
void DoSomething(MyObj obj)
{
    obj.Something = "foo";
}
```

Since no new instance is created, the local `obj` variable still points to the same in-memory instance which was passed to the method.  That reference is followed and the original instance is modified so that modification will be visible outside of the method after the method completes.

Comment: thanks a lot @David, you taught me the thing I didn't know about oriented object

Comment: @kevricher This has nothing to do with object oriented programming, this is just the difference between value and reference semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Then change your method to return `T` like below using Generic. Essentially, you are creating the object but not returning it and thus it becomes `null` when goes outside the function scope

```
public T HandlingT<T>(T obj){
```

If `T` is just a placeholder for actual object then you should just have like

```
public T HandlingT(T obj){
    if(condition && obj == null){
        obj = new T();
    }
    //...handling object T

   return obj;
}
```

Comment: I think the generics bit is just a red herring here, looks like OP is just using `T` as a placeholder for the real code. Also, changing the parameter to `ref` should be enough here (though I prefer a return like you've used)

Comment: @DavidG, yes very well could be but am confused with the use of `T` in question but anyways the point is clear enough

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding using T , here I'm refering T to a class I created